# Can I still use PromiseProxyMixin with Ember.Controller?

Tags: javascript, ember-1

The Ember documentation describes `PromiseProxyMixin` as:

> A low level mixin making ObjectProxy, ObjectController or ArrayControllers promise-aware.

(Note it does not mention `Controller`.)

I have been using the `PromiseProxyMixin` in a `ModalController` that was originally extended from `Ember.ObjectController`.

Now that `ObjectController` is deprecated (Ember 1.11), I have converted this controller to extend `Ember.Controller` and it no longer works as expected.

Specifically, the properties of the object that are returned to the `promise` property are not automatically set in the `Controller` (as they were in an `ObjectController`.

My `isFulfilled` observer is still firing, but the properties that should be merged from the returned object are not set.

The documentation also states:

> As the controller is an ObjectController, and the json now its content, all the json properties will be available directly from the controller.

So I guess I'll just have to manually set these properties from now on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the merging of properties returned by the `Promise` no longer happens automatically my options seemed to be:

1. Convert the `Controller` back to `ObjectController` (wrong direction)
2. Manually merge the properties of the object returned by the `Promise` (this might make sense if I did it in a generic `MyProxyMixin` or some-such)
3. Convert `Controller` to `ObjectProxy` (not sure about this)
4. Use Ember's `ProxyMixin`

I would've preferred #4, but there have been some gyrations around this mixin (it was enabled as an Ember.FEATURE for a little while but appears to have been made private again.)

Ultimately I opted for #2. (I just updated my code to copy the properties I needed to the `Controller`.)

Answer (score 0):

PromiseProxyMixin hasn't been deprecated and is used in other contexts. The [current API docs](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/5574f1947752bc0b1e75793dff9a16ed2e6da02d/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/promise_proxy.js#L37) on git makes no mention of controllers. The wording your looking at has changed, I would assume it's safe to just keep using.

> As the proxy is an ObjectProxy, and the json now its content, all the json properties will be available directly from the proxy.

```
// Assuming the following json:
{
  firstName: 'Stefan',
  lastName: 'Penner'
}
// both properties will accessible on the proxy
proxy.get('firstName') //=> 'Stefan'
proxy.get('lastName')  //=> 'Penner'
```

Comment: _PromiseProxyMixin hasn't been deprecated_ True, but `ObjectController` is and for whatever reason the automatic merging of properties returned by the `Promise` does not occur with `Controller`. The rest of the functionality of `PromiseProxyMixin` works though. I was able to observe `isFulfilled` w/o incident.